# What happened to the Ubuntu online tour?

Tags: ubuntu-website, history-of-ubuntu

It's not that I don't have Ubuntu or want to know more about it, which is pretty obvious since I ran Ubuntu since November 2017. My only is question is why is the online tour still running Ubuntu 14.04? That version is extremely outdated! When I first realized it I thought it was because Gnome isn't in LTS yet and it will be updated once 18.04 get's released. When 18.04 got released, I checked and the tour was still running 14.04 on the Unity desktop. I really feel like it should be updated since newcomers will check the tour then install Ubuntu and not get what they wanted. Is the online tour discontinued and dead or are they still updating it?

Answer (score 2):

I've opened an Issue [asking for the tour to be updated](https://github.com/canonical-websites/tour.ubuntu.com/issues/7), please give it a +1 (thumb emoji)! However I suspect what was [stated](https://github.com/canonical-websites/tour.ubuntu.com/issues/4#issuecomment-296223237) on an Issue asking for an update to 16.04 LTS still applies: it's too low a priority to be worked on though of course they welcome contributions to get it fixed (edit: [this is in fact the case - the Ubuntu online tour is no longer supported](https://github.com/canonical-websites/tour.ubuntu.com/issues/7#issuecomment-385615070)).

Comment: After a million years, there is finally an answer. Well, now that I know it's no longer supported,  I guess it'll always be on 14.04. What a shame! Thanks for the info.